# Is it conventional to simply reference Oracle's imq.jar and jms.jar?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

I was handed an application where these two JARs are simply included in the lib directory. As far as I can tell, they aren't actually distributed separate from the Java Enterprise Edition packages. Assuming that they have everything that I need, is this a good idea? It does cut down on the size of the deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Those jar files are just needed in the classpath. If they are you don't need to include them in the deployment.

It's not sane to remove any package for the Java EE installation if that's what you mean. It could affect other apps that do need those packages and the bugs are kinda of hard to track down when they happen.

**UPDATE**

So the question would be is it OK to run Java EE libs without a Java EE insall?. If there is no Java EE installation and that app is meant to be run with a JRE there is nothing wrong with that. It's just an app that needs the JRE plus 2 libs from the Java EE, just make sure (thats the tricky part) those libs don't have any dependencies from other Java EE libs

**UPDATE**

Both apparently don't need other dependencies but if you want to make sure download them from the maven repositories.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I'm concerned with how to deploy them in a sane way. Is it wise to separate these two JARs from a JEE installation and reference them in a project?

Comment: Your question is unclear then.
It's not sane to remove any package for the JEE installation if that's what you mean. Why would it affect your deployment installation? If those jars are already in your JEE install and you want to remove them for your deployment that's OK

Comment: There is no JEE installation. Instead of installing JEE, these libs have been copied from a JEE installation and included in the lib directory for a particular application. This doesn't seem wise to me, but they are the only required libs from the JEE environment to enable a desktop application to use the JMS APIs.

Comment: So the question would be is it OK to run J2EE libs without a j2EE insall?.
If there is no J2EE installation and that app is meant to be run with a JRE there is nothing wrong with that. It's just an app that needs the JRE plus 2 libs from the JEE, just make sure(thats the tricky part) those libs don't have any dependencies from other J2EE libs

Comment: If you make that comment your answer, I think I can accept it. It's pretty clear that (for at least the state of the system now), there are no dependencies on other JEE libraries, since it works without apparent errors.

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether you want to deploy your application on some Java EE application server (Glassfish, JBoss etc.) or keep it outside. In latter case, it is not question if that's good idea or not - you **have** to include imq.jar and jms.jar in your application to be able to communicate with JMS message broker.

I have used this approach many times, one example is standalone application that sends SMS by putting it on a message queue. On the other side, there is a MDB within application server that listens on particular message queue and sends the SMS.